# Returning Array with Object[] method

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a method that is supposed to populate a JComboBox with data gathered from my database, but the only way I've seen to be able to grab the info from the database, is in an Array. And I need to convert the array to object[] before I can completely compile my program. Is there any way to actually do this? Or is this going to be a long process? My code is as below.

```
public Object[] getId() {
  Connection con;
  Statement stmt;
  ResultSet rs;

  //Object[] returnId;
  Array returnId;
  try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:collegesys","root","0blivi0n");

    stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT `id` FROM main");

    while(rs.next()) {
      returnId = rs.getArray("id");
    }

    con.close();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return returnId.toObject();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
return (Object[]) returnId.getArray();
```

I gather that you want to collect the value of the `"id"` column from all rows of table `main`. Your code will not do that as it's organized. Try this instead:

```
public Object[] getId() {
  Connection con;
  Statement stmt;
  ResultSet rs;

  //Object[] returnId;
  ArrayList<Object> returnId = new ArrayList<Object>();
  try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:collegesys","root","0blivi0n");

    stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT `id` FROM main");

    while(rs.next()) {
      returnId.add(rs.getObject("id"));
    }

    con.close();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return returnId.toArray(new Object[returnId.size()]);
}
```

Of course, if you have a better idea of the data type in column `id`, you can be more specific about the return type and how you get the value (e.g., `String[]` and `rs.getString("id")` or `Integer[]` and `rs.getInt("id")`).

Comment: Okay, I've done this. But Now I'm getting the initialization error from my array. how the hell am I supposed to initialize that?

Comment: @Nathan - the problem is that in your code, it's possible to reach the `return` statement without anything being assigned to `returnId`. You need to look at your logic and reorganize things. I updated my answer to show one approach.